# Symbol names in English

Tags: reading-aloud, symbols

There are some symbols which you can see on your keyboard, I'd like to know how do you say their names in English. I know some of them, so I'll would be appreciate it if you complete and correct the following list.

```
( = Open Parenthesis
) = Close Parenthesis
[ = Open Bracket
] = Close Bracket
{ = Open Curly Bracket
} = Close Curly Bracket
* = Asterisk
& = Ampersand
^ = Caret
% = Percent Sign
$ = Dollar Sign
# = hash Sign
@ = At Sign
! = Exclamation
~ = tilde
' = Single Quote
" = Double Quote
` = grave
< = Open Angle Bracket
> = Close Angle Bracket
/ = Forward Slash (Slash)
\ = Backward Slash
- = Dash, Line, Hyphen
_ = Underscore, Underline
. = dot, point
? = Question Mark
| = Pipe
```

Math Signs:

```
+ =
- =
×(*) =
÷(/) =
=(equal) =
```

Comment: Exclamation (mark), tilde, back quote. Plus sign, minus sign, equal sign. Dot is also a decimal (point) and period.

Comment: Here is a similar question, but asking "[What do programmers call these punctuation marks? (Parentheses, brackets, ticks, etc.)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108169)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of symbols with names:

http://www.computerhope.com/keys.htm

Note some of the symbols have several names

```
 # :  Number sign, Hash, Sharp, Pound

 ! :  Exclamation Mark, Bang

 { : Curly bracket, Open brace

 ~ : Tilde

 `  : Back quote, Acute, Backtick

 \  : Backslash
```

Comment: Isn't the backquote a [grave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent), not an [acute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent)?